# When running sudo apt-get upgrade fails with 'libpam-runtime' is missing final newline

Tags: installation, debian, package, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to get some packages to install in `Raspian Jessy`, running command:
`sudo apt-get upgrade`

but it fails with:
`'libpam-runtime' is missing final newline`

I'm tried numerous suggestions I found online like: 
1) reinstalling the package with:
`apt-get install libpam-runtime --reinstall`

This does nothing different.

etc.

`Full output looks like:
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  bind9-host debconf debconf-i18n debconf-utils libbind9-90 libdns-export100 libdns100 libgcrypt20
  libgnutls-deb0-28 libgnutls-openssl27 libirs-export91 libisc-export95 libisc95 libisccc90 libisccfg-export90
  libisccfg90 liblwres90 libwbclient0 perl perl-base perl-modules samba-common
22 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/9,237 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14.3 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Reading changelogs... Done
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'libpam-runtime' is missing final newline`

**updated error**
When I try to run:
the `purge` command I got:
`dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'libpam0g:armhf' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)`

But, I have not found a solution after nearly 3 hours.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to completely uninstall package and install it again

```
 sudo apt-get purge libpam-runtime
 sudo apt-get install libpam-runtime
```

Comment: I had tried this as well, this didn't work. Any other thoughts? *I'm at a total loss*

Comment: You can delete(or remane for backup) file "/var/lib/dpkg/info/libpam-runtime.list" and try to reinstall package again

Comment: That atleast gave me a different error. can you see above and help please?

Comment: DO NOT under any circumstances run those commands on an AWS Instance! You will not be able to log back into it!

Answer (score 0):

Your files on libpam can't complete or corrupt. I reccomended your download frpm library sites of libpam and trying manual installing I think so safety.